# Why does my C++ to hexadecimal conversion cause different formatting?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++, type-conversion, std

I have a memory address as a `const void *` variable. For printing that memory address as hexadecimal I'm using the following function(s):

```
inline void replace_all(std::string& text, const std::string& replace, const std::string& replacement)
{
    if (replace.empty())
    {
        return;
    }

    size_t start_position = 0;
    while ((start_position = text.find(replace, start_position)) != std::string::npos)
    {
        text.replace(start_position, replace.length(), replacement);
        start_position += replacement.length();
    }
}

template <typename T>
std::string to_hexadecimal(T value)
{
    std::stringstream stream;
    stream << std::hex;
    stream << value;
    auto output_string = stream.str();
    replace_all(output_string, ",", "");
    replace_all(output_string, ".", "");
    replace_all(output_string, "\xA0", "");

    // Truncate the leading zeros
    while (output_string.at(0) == '0')
    {
        output_string = output_string.substr(1, output_string.size() - 1);
    }

    return output_string;
}
```

I'm wondering why different users of my software required me to add the `replace_all()` calls for replacing all commas, dots and blanks (`0xA0` bytes) in the hexadecimal address output to ensure correct behavior.

Without the `replace_all()` calls, users had outputs like:

```
000,01D,992,8B0,000
000.01D.992.8B0.000
000 01D 992 8B0 000
```

But what I really always want to get is something like this:

```
1D9928B0000
```

I'm wondering why the different kinds of formats happen and how to prevent further formatting surprises to be sure the output is always the same formatting wise.

The way I'm invoking the `to_hexadecimal()` function is like this:

```
const auto memory_address = reinterpret_cast<PVOID>(0x1234567812345678);
const auto hexadecimal_memory_address = to_hexadecimal(memory_address);
std::cout << hexadecimal_memory_address << std::endl;
```

Comment: What is `\xA0` doing in your output in the first place? Latin1 non-breaking space?

Comment: Wouldn't this depend on T and the _possible_ set of values it will emit? Seems like the input could be "whatever" unless there is a constraint or contractual guaranatee.

Comment: That is, can T be constrained to `void*` ("the memory address")?

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve] that produces that hex output? It is unclear how `to_hexadecimal` is invoked. Don't forget to include any overloaded `operator <<` that corresponds to the `T` being passed in as the argument.

Comment: C++ is a bit disappointing when it comes to both encodings and localization.  Make sure your users are aware of what encoding your application is using.

Comment: *"I have a memory address as a `const void *` variable."* -- where is this variable in your code? Since you know its type, why use a template?

Comment: I added the way I'm invoking the `to_hexadecimal()` function. Also the template is to retain generic usability of the function. It might as well be just `std::string to_hexadecimal(PVOID value)`

Comment: *"to retain generic usability of the function"* -- this smells of over-engineering, of creating new problems by trying to solve problems that don't yet exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your intention is not fully understandable. The inserter operator is alread overloaded to print out pointer. If you have a pointer, regardless which, you can simply insert the address into a stream:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {

    double d = 3.14;

    // Print address in hex
    std::cout << &d << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

Your function does not work, because you also allow, via a template, to pass any type.

If the type is a plain double, then the `stream << value;` will not convert it to a hex. And espcially not to an address. Hex or not, does'nt matter. Simply no conversion.

But as said. All that is not needed. Please use the above approach.

Comment: Yes, you're right. Printing the address works and converts it to hexadecimal.